# Why is "git log", when using cmder's git for windows, showing all commits on my branch?

Tags: git, git-log, git-config, cmder, git-for-windows

Typically `git log` would show the most recent commits on my branch and I can scroll back through the history to see earlier commits.

I have used cmder on all my windows machines as terminal of choice, especially when using git, I've never had this issue before. Cmder comes shipped with git-for-windows which again has never caused this issue before.

Currently setting up a new PC with cmder and I've just noticed this strange behaviour when using git log that is displays all my commits all the way to the first commit. This is obviously not useful as i'm interested in the latest commits only.

I ran `git log` I expected to see the latest commits with option to scroll through earlier ones.

Instead the terminal spits out all commits and scrolls to the first one ever made.

Perhaps there is some git config incorrectly set?

Comment: I am aware that i can show a limited number of commits by something like this: `git log -5` will give the last 5 commits in the log

Comment: looks like a problem with how the pager is configured. Is `less` installed ? does `GIT_PAGER=less git log` allow you to scroll as you expect ?

Comment: Do you mean that `git log` is not using a PAGER and you get the entire log in one go rather than a page at a time. IDK which pager should be used on Windows, but on other OSs it would be `less`. See also the `git` manual page regarding the `GIT_PAGER` and `core.pager`.

Comment: link to [the aforementioned man page](https://git-scm.com/docs/git/2.26.0#Documentation/git.txt-codeGITPAGERcode)

Comment: Less is installed and available. I tried your suggestion @LeGEC but it doesn't seem to change anything.

Comment: @RichardSmith Indeed I get the entire log in one go. I've never seen this before on Windows

Comment: Also just to clarify that this is only an issue when using the cmder terminal with included git-for-windows. I've installed git standalone and can use `git log` with the expected results in git bash

Comment: Unable to get this to work - it's likely a bug in the current full version of cmder. As a workaround i'm using cmder-mini and starting git bash from there